# Doubt in cdf and memoryless property

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am a beginner. I recently started probability and statistics from Ross. Kindly clarify me the following

> Let $X$ be an exponential distributed random variable with parameter 3. Suppose $Y = F(X)$ where $F$ is the cdf of $X$. Then, $Y$ is given as uniform distribution on interval $[0,1]$.

***My doubt***

1) $F(x) = 1-e^{-3x}$. How is this uniform distribution. Uniform distribution means (from what I understood) in an interval pdf (probability density function) must be constant and area $= 1$. But graph of $F(x) = 1-e^{-3x}$ (exponential after mirrored with respect to $x$ axis first, then $y$-axis mirrored and then translated along $y$ direction by $+1$. [(Link)](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk0318GWZr3YjrSwo9fNg0Soy-fzsAA%3A1582183544540&ei=eDROXs3MIPHWz7sPu_ObsA0&q=1-e%5E-3x+graph&oq=1-e%5E-3x+graph&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39.27865.35677..36668...0.2..0.136.475.0j4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i8i7i30j0j0i5i30j0i8i30j0i8i7i10i30.CkRDDEnw9V8&ved=0ahUKEwjN6JCBzd_nAhVx63MBHbv5BtYQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) This is not uniform right???

2) I understood mathematically memoryless property. But how to vizualise it?

$$ P(X>t+s \mid X>s)=P(X>t) $$

For example, in case of exponential distribution, $P(X>t+s \mid X>s)$ graph why it shifts to $x>t$ to the right? Kindly enlighten.

[image]

Comment: $F(x)$ is certainly not the CDF of a uniform distribution, but this has nothing to do with whether $Y = F(X)$ is uniform or not. Indeed, since $F$ is strictly increasing on $[0, \infty)$, it has an inverse function $F^{-1}$. Then, for $y\in[0,1]$ we have $$ P(Y \leq y)=P(F(X)\leq y)=P(X\leq F^{-1}(y))=F(F^{-1}(y))=y $$ and this is exactly the CDF of a uniform distribution over $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Sir i did not understand. What you have calculated is F(y) which is cdf of y(random variable). In theorem, F(x) is to be proved as uniform distribution(cdf happend to be uniform distribution and not cdf - as cdf of some uniform distribution). I think i am not catching the point. kindly elaborate

Comment: Sir also kindly help me in visualizing memoryless property

Comment: The question asks to prove that $Y$ defined as in the problem has a uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ over $[0, 1]$. There are several ways to identify a distribution of a RV, but one such way is to compute its CDF and check if this matches the distribution to investigate. What I did in my answer indeed computed the CDF of $Y$ and checked that this matches that of $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$.

Comment: The memorylessness property may be recast as $$ P(X-s>t\mid X>s)=P(X>t). $$ In other words, regarding $X$ as a waiting time (for a bus or an alpha-decay, for instance), then provided that nothing happened up to time $s$, the extra amount of time $X-s$ you have to wait behaves exactly the same as the amount of time you have wait from the beginning. That way, this waiting has "no memory" and always behaves like every moment is a fresh start.

Comment: Sir when i read in wiki about uniform distribution, it says in an interval(open or closed) pdf is constant and area = 1. If i have to say some z(a random variable) as uniform or not, i need to check pdf is like above or not. Another way is to to calculate cdf in that interval and see if P(Z<=z in that interval) = 1. But will that ensure its pdf is constant in that interval? If we take the above case $Y=F(x)=1-e^{-3x}$ graph is not constant in (0,1) and also its area is not 1?

Comment: I understood intuition behind memoryless property but i did not understnd the 1st case. Pls explain sir.

Comment: I guess that you are perhaps confusing random variables with their distributions. (A random variable $X$ is a function from the sample space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and its distribution describes how the values of $X$ "spreads over".) As I mentioned from the beginning, the fact that the random variable $Y = 1 - e^{-3X}$ is not a linear function of another random variable $X$ has nothing to do with whether $Y$ has a uniform distribution or not. I am not sure why you keep telling that $F(x)=1-e^{-3x}$ is not a constant, which has nothing to do with identifying the distribution of $Y$...

Comment: @SangchulLee Sir pls see the image above. THis is what i did. Please correct me wehre i went wrong. Pardon my ignorance. Aprreciate your patience

Comment: Asked and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/450604/119261. Please avoid cross-posting in general.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/450604/119261.